# Do ‘und’ and ‘till’ make “until” a tautology?

Tags: etymology, till-until

The [English Oxford Dictionaries’ definition of the word 'until'](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/until) lists the following as its etymology:

> Middle English: from Old Norse und 'as far as' + till (the sense thus *duplicated*)

Etymonline [similarly states](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=until):

> c.1200, from O.N. *und* "as far as, *up to*" (related to O.E. end; see end) + till "until, *up to*".

Looking at the two entries, it seems that until is made up of two roots which mean the same thing, rendering the word something of a tautology ('*up to up to*'). Or does it? Etymonline also states that it is related to the word *end* which would effectively make the etymology of *until* mean, '*up to the end*'. This makes some sort of sense.

The OED (online), however, does not list *until* as being related to [*end*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/end). Moreover, Etymonline does not mention *und* in its entry for *end* either, which makes things a little confusing.

So, is *until* something of a tautology? If so, is it unique in this aspect?

Comment: It may be that *und* is Old Norse for "as far as" but *till* still exists in Swedish for *to*; so *until* could be analysed as "all the way to". But I would have thought the OED could have done that.

Comment: I don't think *tautology* is the right word here, more like *redundant*.

Comment: Interesting question.  To answer it, I think we’d need to see how _und_, _till_, and _und+till = until_ were all used.  If all are distinct, then it’s probably not a tautology; but there may be substantial overlap.  (Unfortunately, Old Norse isn’t a language I have any experience with.)

Comment: @PeterOlson A tautology is, by definition, redundant. So is _pleonasm_.

Comment: Perhaps more a pleonasm than a tautology?

Comment: _Quagmire_ has overtones of tautology (bog bog).

Comment: I like [lukewarm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lukewarm&searchmode=none) as an example of this ubiquitous **relic redundancy** in modern compounds.

Comment: If 'until' can be regarded as a tautology, then 'up until' is even more tautological!

Answer (score 8):

It may have been *perceived* as redundant  by some in the 13th century (but I've seen no evidence of that). It's certainly not redundant now, and to impute redundancy to it is an instance of the etymological fallacy.

Since it's originally a northern term, I'd guess that it represented a conflation of the terms used by two interpenetrating speech communities, the ON and OE.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is true, but it is equally true that most English speakers don't know Old Norse, so while its etymology may be redundant, its current usage is not.